# Pronunciation of street names, cities, rare surnames and city districts

Tags: pronunciation

I have problem with finding IPA for some street names, cities, rare surnames and city districts, basicly words I can’t find in dictionary.

For example I need to pronounce word ‘Gorgie’, /ˈɡɔrɡiː/ but my first guess was something similar to /dʒɔrdʒi:/.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is where Google comes in handy. The first hit on *Gorgie* gives a Wikipedia entry for an area of Edinburgh. If that's what you're looking for, Wikipedia tells you it's pronounced /ˈɡɔrɡiː/.

Comment: Yes, but only sometimes. There is a lot of words I can't find pronuciation for using google e.g. 'Niddrie'

Comment: Well, I googled "Niddrie pronunciation" and got [this](https://www.howtopronounce.com/niddrie/). I have no idea how authoritative it is.

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this are what Google is really good for. Google "Gorgie pronunciation" and you're likely to be driven to a number of sites.

If that doesn't work, you just have to guess, based on spelling. I would have guessed /ˈɡɔrdʒiː/, because ‹g› before ‹i› is for historical reasons usually /dʒ/, and I would have been wrong: it's /ˈɡɔrɡiː/. Don't let that bother you. Practically nobody knows these pronunciations except the people who live there, and they are usually delighted with your mispronunciations: it makes them feel superior. I caused great mirth when I first came to St Louis and gave all the French street names more or less French pronunciations.

Comment: Indeed, as noted in the *Los Angeles Times* story "['Los Feliz': How you say it tells about you and L.A.](http://www.latimes.com/local/great-reads/la-me-los-feliz-20130507-dto-htmlstory.html)," the USGS gave up on trying to record the pronunciation of place names long ago. People need to bumble through *Rio Grande, Ohio*; *Pierre, South Dakota*; *Genoa, Nevada*; and so on without official guidance.

Answer (score 1):

For such pronunciation problems there are special dictionaries of pronunciation.
http://www.amazon.de/Cambridge-English-Pronouncing-Dictionary-CD-ROM/dp/0521152550

It is really rare that a proper name isn't registered in Daniel Jones. It covers only British pronunciation, but is  very exact, giving the most frequent pronunciation first, and then possible variants.

Comment: For place names there are also 'pronouncing gazeteers'. But they're not going to be very helpful with the names of very small places or very new towns.